# Simplex/duplex printing in Lotus Notes 10

Tags: lotus-notes, barcode-printing

I would like to take control of the simplex/duplex print option inside of notes by sending printer sequences at the right time.

Has anyone had any luck with that?

How about setting right, left, top, bottom margins on the print?  Document management without full control of the print process sucks!

Comment: There is one rule that applies to Notes since the very first day back in the nineties (and it never changed): Notes is not made to print... Therefor there is little to no automation for printing. The only chance is to make a special Print form where you can set some parameters like margins, but not much. The only LotusScript Command is NotesUIDocument.Print, but it does not have many options.